# Predictive Distribution with Normal Prior

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bayesian

Given $\Theta = \theta$, let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n, X_{n+1} \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta, \sigma^2)$ be independent.

$\Theta \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta_0, \tau^2)$.

What is the **easiest way** to find the distribution of $X_{n+1}\mid X_1, \dots, X_n$?

I am looking only for **hints**. How I would start this is
$$f_{X_{n+1} \mid X_1, \dots, X_n}(t \mid x_1, \dots, x_n) = \dfrac{f_{X_1, \dots, X_{n+1}}(x_1, \dots, x_{n}, t)}{f_{X_1, \dots, X_{n}}(x_1, \dots, x_n)}$$
and conditioned on $\Theta$, we know that the $X$s are independent, so
$$f_{X_1, \dots, X_{n+1}}(x_1, \dots, x_{n}, t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X_1, \dots, X_{n+1}\mid \Theta}(x_1, \dots, x_n, t\mid \theta)\pi(\theta)\text{ d}\theta$$
and we can write $$f_{X_1, \dots, X_{n+1}\mid \Theta}(x_1, \dots, x_n, t\mid \theta) = f_{X_1 \mid \Theta}(x_1\mid\theta)\cdots f_{X_n\mid \Theta}(x_n\mid \theta)f_{X_{n+1}\mid \Theta}(t\mid \theta)$$
by independence, and similarly for the denominator, but this looks *disgusting*.

Comment: The distribution of $X_{n+1}\mid X_1, \dots, X_n$ is the distribution of $X_{n+1}$, by independence.

Comment: @Augustin If they are conditioned on $\Theta=\theta$, they are independent. I don't think this is necessarily the case when working with them unconditionally.

Comment: Right, sorry I didn't understand that the independence was conditional.

Comment: I have not actually work out the integral. The integrand looks disgusting, but it seems it is not too hard to simplify and obtain a Gaussian pdf integrand. Have you try a little bit more?

Comment: @BGM I've given up on it for now, might look at it at a later time. But I had that it was proportional to something like $$\exp\left\{\dfrac{-1}{2}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\left(\dfrac{x_i - \theta}{\sigma_0}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\theta-\theta_0}{\tau_0}\right)^2  \right]\right\}$$
if we assume that $t = x_{n+1}$ for convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. To get the joint distribution of $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_{n+1}$, compute the moment generating function. This will get you the mean vector and covariance matrix. Additional hint, if you need it:

> Condition on $\Theta$.

2. To get the conditional distribution of $X_{n+1}$ given $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, Google "multivariate normal conditional distribution".  (The general formula is tricky to prove, so maybe you can cite the formula without proof.)

If you need to write out the conditional density of $X_{n+1}$ given the rest, it might help to use

> the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula).